# location in google map api and apple MKMapKit are different

Tags: dictionary, ios8

i am using maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json? for route plotting in objc . when i plot the line there is a slight change of coordinate , means the pin and the polyline don't intersect . Is there any way to plot with exact points in MKMap.

my code

```
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&mode=driving", agentLati, agentLogi, userLati, userLogi]];


..........

 if (polyLine !=nil) {
                [_route_Map removeOverlay:polyLine];
            }
            polyLine = [[MKPolyline alloc]init];
//            polyLine = [self polylineWithEncodedString:[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"]];
               polyLine = [self polylineWithEncodedString:[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"]];
            [_route_Map addOverlay:polyLine];
```